# How can I detect when my application goes through recreation phase

Tags: android

As i already know, activities in android can go through recreation phase, e.g. be destroyed and than created again, as mentioned here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle

To preserve state of my app during lifecycle changes, I use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in my activity, and everything goes fine.

But, when Application is recreated, I cannot correctly save/restore state, cause there are already a lot of another activities in my app, that doesn't support saving/restoring state.
What I what to achieve, is simply drop stack of all activities, that was previously opened, and launch app from the scratch.

Can anybody help my, how can I detect application recreation event, so I can told my app, that it should **not restore** any previously saved state?

**Update:**
Same problem described in this article, but It doesn't provide solution to my problem
https://medium.com/@elye.project/dont-keep-activities-alone-is-not-enough-for-testing-407b7c01bd60

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is the following:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static boolean isFirstInit = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(isFirstInit) {
            isFirstInit = false;
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                // is after process restart
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But I think you're just supposed to properly implement state persistence in the first place.

I know, as a user, that an app that restarts from scratch just because I opened the camera and uploaded an image to Google Photos and then came back to it, is very annoying.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a flag under your [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class. Though below example is just one way to maintain the state. There are multiple ways like storing in BaseActivity or Listening the activity state changes and saving the state.

> Base class for maintaining global application state. You can provide your own implementation by creating a subclass and specifying the fully-qualified name of this subclass as the "android:name" attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag. The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created.

You can try with below example and maintaining flag. So whenever application is launched `BaseApp`will be the first one to exectue.

```
public class BaseApp extends Application{

private boolean isAppRestarted;

  @Override public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  isAppRestarted = true;
  }

  public static boolean isAppRestarted() {
  return isAppRestarted;
  }

}
```

One can access the `isAppRestarted` state and know whether it has restarted or not. I mean fresh start. After couple of seconds you can change the state using some timer or based on user activity(making `isAppRestarted` to `false`).

Comment: After app recreation you flag `isAppRestarted` will be cleared too

Comment: @IvanSyabro Once app is recreated - `onCreate` of Application would be called first before any other android component and we are setting a flag to true there. So we know that app has restarted. After couple of seconds or on any user activity you can resest that flag.

Comment: but `onCreate` will be called both for recreation and first app create

Comment: This will always be `true`.